# Topology and continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

I have a function$$ f : (\mathbb{R}, O) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \text{standard})$$ be given by $f(x) = x.$ I am new to this so based on the different topology in general how to determine and show if $f$ continuous or not given:

• $O = \{∅, \mathbb{R}\}$;

• $O = \text{standard}$;

• $O$ is the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Use the definition of continuity directly. In each case, take open sets $U$ in $(\Bbb R, \text{standard})$ and see whether $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $(\Bbb R, O)$.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the definition: $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is open for open $U\subseteq Y$.

Now since your function $f$ is special, namely $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x$ then for any subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}(A)=A$.  Therefore we can reduce the problem to:

> **Statement:** the standard topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is a sub-topology of $O$, i.e. $\tau\subseteq O$.

1. $O=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ - no, because $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ while $(0,1)\not\in O$.
2. Obviously if $O$ is standard then they are equal, in particular the statement holds.
3. By the definition the discrete topology consists of **all** subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. In particular it contains the standard topology, hence the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

1. $f$ is not continuous function on $\mathbb{R}.$ Take $U=(0,1) \in (\mathbb{R}, standard),$ and you can check that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open in $(\mathbb{R}, indiscrete).$
2. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$
3. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$